# Android: How to correctly synchronize iteration over Set when another thread can remove elements from the Set?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, synchronization

Why does a call to `removeListener()` in the following code throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` when another thread is using the iterator in `fireEvent()`?

```
public class MyClass {

    private Set<Object> synchronizedListeners;

    public MyClass() {
        synchronizedListeners = Collections.synchronizedSet(
                new LinkedHashSet<Object>());
    }

    public void addListener(Object listener) {
        synchronizedListeners.add(listener);
    }

    public synchronized void removeListener(Object listener) {
        synchronizedListeners.remove(listener);
    }

    public void fireEvent() {
        synchronized (synchronizedListeners) {
            for (Object listener : synchronizedListeners) {
                // do something with listener
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From my understanding, since I'm using `synchronized (synchronizedListeners)` in `fireEvent()`, this should block any other thread that calls `removeListener()`, till the iteration in `fireEvent()` is complete at which point it should be safe to remove an element from this Set. But this doesn't seem to be the case. What am I doing wrong?

Possibly related: [Java synchronized block vs. Collections.synchronizedMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567068/java-synchronized-block-vs-collections-synchronizedmap)

**Edit:** It was pointed out that I was unnecessarily synchronizing the removeListener() method. So I tried this version:

```
public void removeListener(Object listener) {
    synchronizedListeners.remove(listener);
}
```

But still got the same error.

**Edit 2:** As assylias pointed out, the problem isn't visible in the above code. I was calling `removeListener()` from inside the for loop in the `synchronized (synchronizedListeners)` block which was causing the error. The fix I ended up using in this case is to remove the listener from another thread:

```
public void removeListener(final Object listener) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronizedListeners.remove(listener);
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: `synchronizedListeners` is protected - do you have any subclasses to MyClass? do they override any of the methods?

Comment: No. I made an edit and changed it to private to make that clearer.

Comment: Your code as it is can't throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`. So the problem is not shown in your question: you might have simplified your code too much before posting and removed the source of the problem. I suggest you try to post a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: You don't call `set.remove()` or `removeListener()` within your `fireEvent` loop, do you?

Comment: Yes, I was calling `removeListener()` from inside `fireEvent`! It was hidden a few layers inside some calls, so I missed it.

Comment: We should all have started there! Glad you found the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't reproduce what you describe - the code at the bottom gives the output shown below - which shows that remove is called in the middle of the iteration, but does not complete until after the iteration because you use a synchronized collection. That's the behaviour one would expect and no ConcurrentModificationException is thrown. Note that I have removed the `synchronized` keyword from the `removeListener` method as it is useless here.

```
fire 100000
remove 100000
done fire 100000
done remove 99999
```

**Conclusion: the problem is somewhere else.** For example, if you have a subclass that overrides the fireEvent method, or if you construct the synchronized set not exactly as in the code you posted.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final MyClass mc = new MyClass();
    final Object o = new Object();
    mc.addListener(o);
    for (int i = 0; i < 99999; i++) {
        Object o1 = new Object();
        mc.addListener(o1);
    }
    Runnable remove = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mc.removeListener(o);
        }
    };

    new Thread(remove).start();
    mc.fireEvent();
}

public static class MyClass {

    protected Set<Object> synchronizedListeners = Collections.synchronizedSet(new LinkedHashSet<Object>());

    public void addListener(Object listener) {
        synchronizedListeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeListener(Object listener) {
        System.out.println("remove " + synchronizedListeners.size());
        synchronizedListeners.remove(listener);
        System.out.println("done remove " + synchronizedListeners.size());
    }

    public void fireEvent() {
        System.out.println("fire " + synchronizedListeners.size());
        synchronized (synchronizedListeners) {
            for (Object listener : synchronizedListeners) {
                // do something with listener
            }
        }
        System.out.println("done fire "  + synchronizedListeners.size());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are synchronizing on two different objects.

The `removeListener` method is synchronized on the `MyClass` instance, whereas the loop inside the `fireEvent` is synchronized on `synchronizedListeners` set.

What you need to do is to synchronize every method that uses the `synchronizedListeners` on the set itself.

Comment: `synchronizedListeners` is a synchronized collections: the remove method is already synchronized. The `removeListener` method does not need to be synchronized but adding synchronization on the set should not make a difference...

Comment: It will. If both blocks (the remove(), and the loop) are synchronized on the same lock, they will never get executed concurrently for the same object. That's how critical sections work.

Comment: remove **IS ALREADY** synchronized internally: `synchronizedListeners = Collections.synchronizedSet(new LinkedHashSet<Object>());`

Comment: But the iterator created from the SynchronizedSet is not. `SynchronizedSet` inherits from `SynchronizedCollection` and the implementation of `iterator` method [does not return synchronized iterators](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.SynchronizedCollection). You need to synchronize them yourself.

Comment: yes and he does that: the iteration is made in fireEvent and is synchronized with the right monitor (the set itself).

Comment: The proper link: [http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.SynchronizedCollection](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.SynchronizedCollection).

It even says: `return c.iterator(); // Must be manually synched by user!`

Comment: I know - I'm saying that he does synchronize the iteration properly: `synchronized (synchronizedListeners) { for (Object listener : synchronizedListeners) {...} }`

Comment: OK. You're right, and I'm blind. But in this case, why does he get `ConcurrentModificationException`?

Comment: The problem is that `SynchronizedCollection.remove()` uses a different (internal) lock object than his synchronized `for` loop. So it's not synchronized at all.

Comment: @npe That's the question. There is nothing in there that could do that. Unless there is a subclass that does something weird for example...

Comment: @MartinMajer remove uses the set itself as a lock (`mutex` in the code).

Comment: @MartinMajer: You're making the same mistake as I did. The internal lock (`mutex` variable) is set to `this` in the constructor. See the links I provided.