# Performance overhead in synchronizing a SynchronizedMap

Tags: java, performance, synchronization

Will there be a performance hit if I synchronize a SynchronizedMap?

For eg:

```
private static Map<Integer, Integer> intMap= Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Integer, Integer>());

public static int doSomething(int mapId) {
  synchronized(intMap) {
    Integer id = intMap.get(mapId);
    if (id != null) {
       //do something
    }
    if (id == null) {
       intMap.put(mapId);
    }
  }
}
```

I have to synchronize explicitly in the above method since its a combination of operations on the synchronizedMap. Since I have to synchronize anyways, is it better to use normal hashmap instead of synchronizedMap?

Will there be a performance issue if I synchronize a synchronizedMap?

Comment: `int id` cannot be `null`.  I think you intended to write `Integer id`

Comment: BTW synchronization can be as cheap as creating a new `Integer` object if the lock is uncontended.

Comment: An interesting question. The anwers so far are basically just saying "Yes", but a proof or evidence would be nice here. I could imagine that a pattern like `sync(x) { sync(x) { foo(); } bar(); }` is actually optimized ("collapsed") to `sync(x) { foo(); bar(); }` because it should be possible to detect that the inner synchronization is superfluous. If nobody else does this, maybe I'll have a look at the bytecode or JITed code on my own later...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there will be a performance hit.  It may not be much, because the JVM is capable of optimizing these locks based on usage, but it will always be there.

There's no reason to use a synchronized map if you're already using the `synchronized` keyword on that object, *unless* you have code in other parts of your program that needs a synchronized Map.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are doing unnecessary synchronization on an already synchronized collection. It will be just as safe and efficient (in fact more efficient) to remove the extra synchronized block.

Further, I performed a small test small-scale: https://gist.github.com/AgentTroll/02b77680efe3b92e350f

(Ignore the license, I had it on one of my projects on GitHub, it's there so people don't think I steal code)

Comment: I cannot remove the synchronized block because my method does more than one operation on the map. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567068/java-synchronized-block-vs-collections-synchronizedmap

Comment: You don't have a synchronization policy clearly documented, so it is difficult to see how your two operations are related to each other.